# How to protect admin page?

Tags: reactjs, security, environment-variables

I'm creating a blog, which has an admin page in the "/admin" path. To protect the page from unauthorized users, I've made it so the content will only be rendered once the correct password is entered. This password is stored in an env file, not as a constant in a js file. Is this a secure approach? How can I further increase security?

Comment: use jwt based token.